# $<P_T>$ distribution as function of PL

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, momentum, computational-physics, simulations

I have a conceptual problem when working with some Monte Carlo generated data. I have to simulate the $P_T$ and $P_L$ distribution for $N$ particles through Monte Carlo methods as follows:
$$\theta \sim U[0, 2\pi] \quad , \quad P \sim U[0,10]\frac{\text{GeV}}{c} $$
Now I simply compute:
$$P_T = P\sin(\theta) \quad , \quad P_L = P\cos(\theta) $$

The resulting histogram is displayed:
[image]

Now I can find $\langle P_T\rangle$ by profiling on each bin on $P_L$. The result is:
[image]

Now the behaviour for $P_L \rightarrow 10$ is obvious and $\langle P_T\rangle \rightarrow 0$.

But I'm asked to justify the dip for low values of $P_L$. That should be due to the fact that particles with low $P$ are forced to also have small $P_T$ and small $P_L$ but I cannot find a way to express it mathematically, in other terms I want to find the analytical expression for $\langle P_T\rangle = f(P_L)$ so I can draw it on the second image. Does anyone have a suggestion?

**MY REASONING (wrong):**

I want to find $pdf(P_T)$ so that I can compute,
$$\mathbb E[P_T] = \int P_T \,pdf(P_T)\,dP_T
$$
and hope for an explicit dependence on $P_L$

For simplicity let's call $P\rightarrow x$:
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{10} & x \in [0, 10] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Now:

$$f_\theta(\Theta) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\pi} & \Theta \in [0, 2\pi] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Let's now call $\sin(\theta) \rightarrow y$ then, thanks to Jacobian formula:

$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{(1-y^2)}} & y \in [-1,1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

I want to compute the pdf of $P_T \rightarrow z = xy$ using the formula:
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)f_Y\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\frac{1}{|x|}dx $$

This means to me:
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{10} \frac{1}{10\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{z^2}{x^2}})}\frac{1}{|x|}dx = \frac{1}{10\pi} \left[\log(\sqrt{x^2-z^2} + x)\right]_{x = |z|}^{x = 10}$$ 
So I finally find:
$$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{10\pi}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{100^2-z^2}+10}{|z|}\right) $$
Now I can find $\langle P_T\rangle = \int zf_Z(z)dz$ but it does not depend on $P_L$

Comment: $P_L$ means longitudinal momentum here, I assume?

Comment: @probably_someone yes, $P$ total momentum , $P_T$ transverse momentum and $P_L$ longitudinal momentum!

Comment: Hint, note that P_T^2 + P_L^2 are distributed like P^2 . Now calculate the distribution for P^2 and evaluate at 0; I would give an involved answer but I'm in a hurry. Maybe later if no one has posted it.

Comment: Hi @Gyromagnetic thank you for your answer. I'm still a bit confused, why should I evaluate it at 0?. So $P\sim U[0,10]$  that means that $P\rightarrow P^{2}$ has a distribution:
$$F_{P^2}(p) = \frac{\sqrt{p}}{10} $$
and the pdf would then be (diff F wrt x):
$$f_{P^2}(p) = \frac{1}{20\sqrt{p}} $$
Am I wrong? 
I'd appreciate so much for your explanation, hope to hear from you later. Have a nice day.